# StringBuilder ToString() performance

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, optimization, stringbuilder

I need to extract the first line of many huge StringBuilders(around 1mb of data each) in a loop. To do so, I thought about doing this:

```
string header;
foreach(StringBuilder strBuilder in bigArray)
    header= strBuilder.ToString().SubString(blabla);
```

but I'm worried the .ToString() method might take too long to execute. Do you have any idea about how I can do this efficiently?

Comment: *I'm worried the .ToString() method might take too long to execute.* - It *might* or it *does*? If it *might*, why not test it?

Comment: Is it just an idea of is it a fact?

Comment: @Michael, a) try it, b) you can use [`StringBuilder.ToString(startIndex, length)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyx7s61s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Have you actually tried it?

Comment: If you are worried about efficiency then couldn't you just keep track of the first line of each string as you are building them up? It doesn't make sense to build up the strings first *then* extract the data out. Regardless, build first, optimize later.

Comment: I agree with Janems, break up the data as your read it. No sense in backtracking

Comment: Just tried it, turns out my initial code was really slow. Using StringBuilder.ToString(startIndex, length) is much faster, though I can't use IndexOf to find the end of the first line. I decided to just display the first 100 characters with an ellipsis instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're looking for a `Substring` alternative that doesn't extract the entire string from the `StringBuilder` you could use the [overload of `ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyx7s61s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes a `start` and `length`:

```
string header;
foreach(StringBuilder strBuilder in bigArray)
{
    header= strBuilder.ToString(start, length);
}
```

Is it faster?  I don't know - you'll have to *measure it* to know for sure.

Another alternative would be to store the "lines" as a collection of string arrays (or `List<List<string>>`) rather than a collection of `StringBuilder`s.

Comment: Your solution has to be faster because you are not allocate 1MB of string every loop and than GC is not forced to cleanup this temporary 1MB big string